# How do I access Mysql Cluster Node ID for Mysql trigger or query use?

Tags: mysql, configuration, triggers, cluster-computing, mysql-cluster

I'm trying to write a Trigger (BEFORE INSERT), and I need to find the cluster id or node id so I can set up a proper calculated id.

Is there a way to retrieve this NodeId or the cluster's id in a query or trigger?

I already checked documentation here, but did not find anything.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-cluster-ndbd-definition.html